# 404 on taxonomy links on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, http-status-code-404

I've read a lot of different posts online on this, but nothing seems to be working.

I'm working on a Wordpress site. Despite individual post links working exactly as intended, (e.g. http://ubicomplab.org/people/jwu), the main taxonomy pages, http://ubicomplab.org/people, etc. redirect to 404.

I have tried modifying .htaccess, deleting .htaccess, disabling plugins, but nothing seems to work. I have also tried rolling back the contents of wp-content to way before this error started occurring, to no effect.

Upon trying to "Edit Page" the 404ing link above, I get an error about how "post 422" is in the trash. There are no posts in the trash, however. I'm not sure why it's specifically post 422.

Could there be something wrong on the server side? If so, what could I do? I have access to the kettle server, but I'm not sure where to begin looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try savings your permalinks again, sometimes this works for me.